# Where should I pay tax as an Indian with an LLC in Delaware in the US?

Tags: united-states, taxes, india, international

I am from India and I am planning to register an LLC in Delaware US and will be operating completely in India. The majority of my customers will be from outside India and I will be paid either through the payment gateway services or PayPal. Now my biggest question is "where should I be paying my tax?". Do I have to pay tax in both India and the US or is one country tax payment enough in my case? Kindly help me. I on the verge of breaking my head finding an answer.